# How do make all environment variables available on the Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have this Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.17.1
ARG GITHUB_TOKEN
ARG REACT_APP_BASE_URL
ARG DATABASE_URL
ARG BASE_URL
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
ENV GITHUB_TOKEN=${GITHUB_TOKEN}
ENV REACT_APP_BASE_URL=${REACT_APP_BASE_URL}
ENV DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL}
ENV BASE_URL=${BASE_URL}
ENV PORT 80
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

But I don't like having to set each environment variable. Is is possible to make all of them available without needing to set one by one?

Comment: I believe you need to differentiate ARG vs ENV first. Hard-coding the GitHub token as ENV will store it inside the image and anyone who can pull that image can get the token. If you want it to be used only during build then only declare ARG and set using `docker build --build-arg`. If you want it to be used during `docker run -e` then only set ENV. What I just show is that there are scenarios you want ARG without ENV and vice versa. So Dockerfile requires us to explicitly assign ARG to ENV if you need the value during build to be available during run.

Comment: @Lukman The image is created only inside my server which is where the application is deployed. I don't even send it to a registry. And I also don't have control over how docker is ran, the only thing I have control is the Dockerfile, so that makes things a little complicated and that's why I'm using both ARG and ENV.

Answer (score 0):

We need to pay attention to next two items before continue:

- As mentioned by @Lukman in comments, `TOKEN` is not a good item to be stored in image unless you totally for internal use, you decide.
- Even we did not specify environment one by one in `Dockerfile`, we still need to define them in some other place, as program itself can't know what environment you really need.

If you no problem with above, let's go on. Basically, I think define the environment (Here, use `ENV1`, `ENV2` as example) in a script, then `source` them in container, and let `app` have ways to access these variables is what you needed.

**env.sh:**

```
export ENV1=1
export ENV2=2
```

**app.js:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var env1 = process.env.ENV1;
var env2 = process.env.ENV2;
console.log(env1);
console.log(env2);
```

**entrypoint.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
source /usr/src/app/env.sh
exec node /usr/src/app/app.js
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:14.17.1
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN chmod -R 755 /usr/src/app
CMD ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**Execution:**

```
$ docker build -t abc:1 .
$ docker run --rm abc:1
1
2
```

**Explain:**

We change `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` in Dockerfile to use customized `entrypoint.sh`, in this `entrypoint.sh`, we will first source `env.sh` which make `ENV1` and `ENV2` visible to subprocess of `entrypoint.sh`.

Then, we use `exec` to replace current process as `node app.js`, so `PID1` becomes `node app.js` now, meanwhile `app.js` still could get the environment defined in `env.sh`.

With above, we no need to define variables in `Dockerfile` one by one, but still our app could get the environment.

Comment: On the first step you mention the creation of a `.sh` file. But sadly I can't do that, I only have access to the Dockerfile. Is there any alternative that focus only on the Dockerfile?

Comment: There should be somewhere that user tell program what `environment variable` should be used. No matter in dockerfile or in other place. You clearly claim don't want to define them one by one in `Dockerfile`, then the solution is only on  so called `other place`.

Comment: This answer is to use `env.sh` & `entrypoint.sh` in local, and COPY them when build. As you said you can't do it, then, if possbile your environment could visit network? If yes, just put `env.sh`, `entrypoint.sh` on internet. Then use `ADD http://website/env.sh /usr/src/app/env.sh` to put it into container when build. Otherwise, I don't know other way to handle your scenario.

Comment: But in your answer I still need to set them, just in a different file. Did I got it right? If is that so, then it's not what I meant. I want to know if it's possible to access the environment variables without having to set them on any files (besides the environment variables itself). But perhaps my question wasn't good to explain what I need. I'll try to elaborate better.

Comment: Didn't catch your point, if you want to have `A` environment, you will have to define it in some place, otherwise how program could know you want to define `A`?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to mention why. I'm using a tool that I set the environment for the machine, but I don't have access to the `.sh` file. So I don't know where it is so I can use the `source /usr/src/app/env.sh` command.
The environment are there. As you can see on my question, I use the `ARG` for selecting specific environment variables, but they are already there. I only have access to the Dockerfile (but I can also create a new `.sh` file if that helps, but not to set the environment variables again, because that loses the point of the question).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different (easy) way.

Start by making your file. Here I'm choosing to use everything on my this is messy and not recommended. It's a useful bit of code though so I thought I'd add it.

```
env | sed 's/^/export /' > env.sh
```

edit it so you only have what you need
`vi env.sh`

Use the below to import files into the container. Change `pwd` to whichever folder you want to share.  Using this carelessly may result in you sharing to many files*

```
sudo docker run -it -v `pwd`:`pwd` ubuntu
```

Assign appropriate file permissions.  I'm using 777 which means *anyone* can read, write, execute - for demonstration purposes. But you only need execute privileges.

Run this command and make sure you add the full stop.

```
. /LOCATION/env.sh
```

If you're confused to where your file is just type `pwd` in the host console.
You can just add those commands where appropriate to your Dockerfile to automate the process.  If I recall there is a VOLUME flag for Dockerfile.